# Optimising finding the index of the highest value in a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, xgboost, argmax

I have a long list of machine learning prediction probabilities for multiple classes and I'm trying to find the highest probability for each prediction. I've implemented the method below for this and it works but it is taking a long time (~10 mins for this step alone) when applied to our typical dataset of order 100 million predictions.

The prediction output (from XGBoost) is of this form:

```
[[9.9696952e-01, 1.9961601e-06, 1.1957183e-03, 2.4479270e-05,1.8083032e-03],
 [9.9696952e-01, 1.9961601e-06, 1.1957183e-03, 2.4479270e-05,1.8083032e-03],
 [9.9696952e-01, 1.9961601e-06, 1.1957183e-03, 2.4479270e-05,1.8083032e-03],
 ...,
]
```

And I'm currently getting the index of the highest value of each of the sub lists and appending it to a separate list as below:

```
# Find maximum class for each pixel and append to list
vals = []
for pred in predictions:
    max_index = np.where(pred == np.amax(pred))[0][0]
    vals.append(max_index)
```

I've run timeit on the numpy steps and got this response:

```
In [37]: %timeit np.where(predictions[0] == np.amax(predictions[0]))[0][0]
6.82 µs ± 25.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

I've had a look around for other functions which can do this functionality but haven't been able to find any. I switched to using a list comprehension instead of a for loop to see if that would speed it up but it made no difference to the time taken to run this step.

Any suggestions of faster ways to implement this?

Comment: Have you tried `np.argmax`?

Comment: Use `xgboost` 's `predict` to return highest probability class vs `predict_proba` to return the raw probabilities.

Comment: @mozway great thanks, brain farted when looking at this again and thought that amax must be the same. It is a bit over 4 times faster on my test machine. So far just rerunning the prediction with predict instead of predict_proba will probably be fastest, providing the same results would occur running predict_proba and predict on the same dataset (I need the probabilities elsewhere in the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.argmax` and set `axis=1` to get `array([0, 0, 0])`

```
import numpy as np

predictions = np.array([[9.9696952e-01, 1.9961601e-06, 1.1957183e-03, 2.4479270e-05, 1.8083032e-03],
                        [9.9696952e-01, 1.9961601e-06, 1.1957183e-03, 2.4479270e-05, 1.8083032e-03],
                        [9.9696952e-01, 1.9961601e-06, 1.1957183e-03, 2.4479270e-05, 1.8083032e-03]
                        ])

output = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
```

---

```
# old solution
vals = []
for pred in predictions:
    max_index = np.where(pred == np.amax(pred))[0][0]
    vals.append(max_index)
```

---

```
all(output == vals)  # True
```